# Django model, filter then group and total cost

Tags: python, django

I have a filter, whereby I want to choose a provider, then for that provider show what circuit types we have and the total cost for those circuit types, from my research the below should work

query:

```
model_provider_costs = CircuitInfoData.objects.filter(provider = "BT").values('circuit_type').annotate(total=Sum('cost_per_month'))
```

it should give me:

```
{'circuit_type': u'DSL', 'toal': Decimal('9,457.00')},
{'circuit_type': u'MPLS', 'toal': Decimal('20,000.00')},
```

but its currently just giving me every circuit infdividually, for example:

```
[
    {'circuit_type': u'DSL', 'total': Decimal('57.00')},
    {'circuit_type': u'MPLS', 'total': Decimal('550.78')},
    {'circuit_type': u'MPLS', 'total': Decimal('547.87')},
    {'circuit_type': u'DSL', 'total': Decimal('57.00')},
    {'circuit_type': u'MPLS', 'total': Decimal('550.78')},
    {'circuit_type': u'DSL', 'total': Decimal('57.00')},
    {'circuit_type': u'MPLS', 'total': Decimal('547.87')},
    ... and so on
```

this is my model:

```
class CircuitInfoData(models.Model):    
    showroom_config_data = models.ForeignKey(ShowroomConfigData,verbose_name="Install Showroom")
    major_site_info = models.ForeignKey(MajorSiteInfoData,verbose_name="Install Site") 
    circuit_type = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=settings.CIRCUIT_CHOICES)    
    circuit_speed = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    circuit_bearer = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    provider = models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=settings.PROVIDER_CHOICES)
    ref_no = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name="Reference No")
    dsl_username = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name="DSL Username",blank=True)
    dsl_password = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name="DSL Password",blank=True)
    dsl_tel_no = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name="DSL Tel No",blank=True)  
    install_location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    install_date = models.DateField()
    cost_per_month = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=8)
    contract_length = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Contact length in years")
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
    service_service_contacts = models.ForeignKey(ServiceContacts)
    subnet = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4',verbose_name="Subnet",blank=True,null=True)
    default_gateway = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4',verbose_name="Default Gateway",blank=True,null=True)
    subnet_mask = models.CharField(max_length=4,verbose_name="Subnet Mask",choices=settings.SUBNET_MASK_CHOICES,blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Circuit Data"
        verbose_name_plural = "Circuit Data"
        ordering = ('showroom_config_data__location','circuit_speed')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s | %s | %s | %s | %s' % (self.showroom_config_data.location,self.major_site_info.location, self.provider, self.circuit_type, self.ref_no)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should probably be

```
model_provider_costs = CircuitInfoData.objects.filter(provider = "BT").prefetch_related('circuit_type').aggregate(Sum('cost_per_month'))
```

Comment: hi this just gives me one sum for the entire provider, not a sum for each circuit type

Comment: If you're filtering by circuit_type use CircuitInfoData.objects.filter(circuit_type=your_value).aggregate....

Comment: i have multiple providers and multiple circuit types, i want to see the total for a specific provider but all types?

Comment: So after filtering out provider use ..select_related('circuit_type') or .prefetch_related('circuit_type')

Comment: More on this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/

Comment: using select related just yields the 1 total sum, i can see from the documentation what it does (basically saves you requerying the same data?) i just dont know what i can then do with this result to further break it down into the types?

Comment: CircuitInfoData.objects.filter(provider="BT",circuit_type=your_type).aggregate(Sum('cost_per_month')) - have you tried this? Anyway it has to be aggregate and not annotate.

Comment: there are multiple circuit types, and i wanted to report on them all, and there could be more in the future so it will be difficult to define a service type

Comment: Then it's prefetch_related,and make sure you have it as many to many in your model

Comment: im pretty new to django and python and most of that documentation is currently over my head, could you show me an example in my scenario, of how i get to the sum of each circuit type?